# pyodbc Cursor Reuse

Tags: python, sql-server-2008-r2, pyodbc

I make multiple queries to my DB from my python code that uses pyodbc to connect to a SQL Server.

```
cursor = connection.connect(connection_string)
qry1 = "Select * FROM Table1"

rows = cursor.execute(qry1).fetchall()

for row in rows:
   qry2 = "Select * FROM Table2"

   rows2 = cursor.execute(qry2).fetchall()

   for row2 in rows2:
      print row2
```

This works and successfully goes through both queries to completion.

How is it that I can reuse the cursor object?

I would think when I ran

```
rows2 = cursor.execute(qry2).fetchall()
```

That `rows` and `rows2` would now point to the same thing (object).

**EDIT: Useful info from pyodbc site**

> Since this reads all rows into memory, it should not be used if there are a lot of rows. Consider iterating over the rows instead. However, it is useful for freeing up a Cursor so you can perform a second query before processing the resulting rows.

[cursor info](http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor)

Comment: I'm having this problem.  What exactly is the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your last statement is false, as `.fetchall()` returns a new list containing all the rows returned by the cursors query, after which you may reuse the cursor. (but i'd test what the cost of a new cursor is before thinking about reusing them.) [well, i don't know if this is really true but it is for the dbapi compatible sqlite3 bindings]

Comment: Looks like you are right.  I've edited my question with info from the pyodbc site.  Thanks!